# How to setup div position absolute to right in relative wrapper with responsive template?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, absolute

How to setup dive with position absolute in relative wrapper-panel, that will happen to be on the right side of that panel, but no fixed amount of pixels in the margin, but responsive to the size of the window and panel that he is in?

float right does not work

```
        <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-content position-relative">
            <h2 class="float-right position-absolute">Make new Route</h2>
            <form method="post">
                <label class="m-0">Route title</label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <label>Path info</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6"><label>Order</label>
                    <div class="js-order-number-target">
                        {% if createRoute.orderNumber is defined %}
                           <select class="form-control" name="order">
                               <option></option>
                           </select>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs float-right">Create New Menu Category</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm following, set right: 0 on the absolute positioned element. Will be aligned to the right of the relative positioned parent.